# Any way to make this c# class thread safe without rewriting?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I love the quick way of creating classes in C# where we can easily create Members without having to implement the get and set code but (as far as I know) they are not thread safe!

```
public class SocksEntry
{
    public int Int1 { get; set; }
    public int Int2 { get; set; }
}
```

Does C# provide a quick an easy way of adding thread safety without having to do this?

```
public class SocksEntry
{
    protected object _lock = new object();

    // internal
    private int _int1 = 0;
    private int _int2 = 0;

    // accessors
    protected int Int1
    {
        get { lock (_lock) return _int1; }
        set { lock (_lock) _int1 = value; }
    }

    protected int Int2
    {
        get { lock (_lock) return _int2; }
        set { lock (_lock) _int2 = value; }
    }
}
```

It obviously makes the whole class a lot bigger and a pain to create compared to the non-thread safe version!

Comment: Might want to have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33559/Handy-wrapper-class-for-thread-safe-property-acces

Comment: Your code with embedded locks in the property accessors is not really thread-safe, either.  The only thing they might buy you are memory barriers if the methods are inlined, but the operations you're 'locking' around are actually already atomic operations.  It would only make sense to lock on higher-level operations that involve coordination of multiple states.

Answer (score 7):

Making a class thread safe is a lot harder than you might even imagine. It might not be enough to put locks around the getters and setters. So the best practice is to have the class not-thread safe and leave the responsibility to the consumer of this class to synchronize the access to it if he needs thread safety. If the consumer doesn't need thread safety, then great, you won't be penalizing the performance of the application just because you built thread safety into the class without even needing it. Why do you think that 99.99% of the classes in .NET are not thread-safe?

Comment: Can you demonstrate it or no?

Comment: Sure, I can. All you have to do is to get rid of the locks in the aformentioned example. Take a look at the first code snippet that the OP provided. That's how the class should look like in most cases. As far as consuming this class in a thread safe manner is concerned, well, this will entirely depend on the context. The OP hasn't really specified how this class is used so it's a bit hard to provide concrete examples without this.

Comment: Ohh you miss understood me i want to see a thread safe, solution.

Comment: Thread safe solution of what? The OP haven't put any context into this question. He hasn't explained how this class is supposed to be used. He hasn't explained why he needs thread safety, etc... So what you call a `thread-safe solution` is some imaginary notion if you do not provide context. Designing thread safe code is an extremely hard thing to do. There are many ways to achieve thread safety, but I have to admit that none of them has ever been easy to me.

Comment: I can imagine that, lately i messing with it alot.

Comment: Ohhh and one more thing can you tell me what is "OP" ?

Comment: @IamStalker, "Original Poster"

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

Auto-implemented properties are great, but when one hits the limitations, that's it.

However, you could create a [Visual Studio snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (like `prop`) that would write the boiler-plate code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thread safety problem you're referring to is something like this:

```
public int Value { get; set; }

public void Foo()
{
    if (this.Value > 0)   // Read the property and make a decision based on its present value
    {
        // Do something with the property, assuming its value has passed your test.
        // Note that the property's value may have been changed by another thread between the previous line and this one.
        Console.WriteLine(this.Value);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the property value may have changed between when you examined it and when you use it. This happens whether you use auto properties, backing variables, or the locks you have in your question. The correct solution depends on how you need your application to behave (what should it do if the value has changed between one line and another). A common solution is to cache the value right in the function where you're using it:

```
public int Value { get; set; }

public void Foo()
{
    int cachedValue = this.Value;

    if (cachedValue  > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cachedValue );
    }
}
```

However, that won't necessarily be correct for what your app is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Most easier and ofthen the only one right approach is to make a class [immutable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx), so only read operations are available.

```
public sealed class SocksEntry
{
    public int Int1 { get; private set; }
    public int Int2 { get; private set; }
}
```

But if this is not possible for a particular business entity - expose some business methods rather than property setters, then it is much easier to sync entire method (think transaction) rather than each property setter which sometimes makes sense set alltogether

```
// lock entire business transaction if possible
public void UpdateEntity(int a, int b)
{
   lock (entityLock)
   {
       Int1 = a;
       Int2 = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Making a class immutable doesn't make it thread-safe in the general case. In the particular case with 2 integer properties it probably does, but imagine a property of type `List<T>` for example. Now even if you made it readonly, there's nothing preventing the consumer of this class calling the getter on the list and then from one thread adding items to the list and from another thread iterating over the list at the same time. As you know `List<T>` is not a thread-safe type and you get into trouble if you don't synchronize the access to this list from the outside.

Comment: I think your example with `List<T>` is not an example of immutable class since as you said you still cann update list

Comment: Yes, but that's true for any reference type. Once you get the reference to the type, you could modify it. So your example with immutable types only applies to value types. How do you handle reference types in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET memory model, reads and writes of native integer types less than or equal to the size of your platform's pointer (i.e. `int` on 32-bit, `long` on 64-bit) are atomic. Atomic means you can read and write it without using locks, and you'll never read or write an incomplete (i.e. half-way between a write) value.

However, .NET does not guarantee that writes will be immediately visible to other threads (meaning you can write in thread A, then read in thread B, and still read an old value). On x86 you get immediate visibility with the architecture, but on other platforms you need to use a `volatile` field or `Thread.MemoryBarrier` after writes. `lock` inserts a memory barrier for you, so you don't need to worry about it.

Another thing to think of is how you *use* the class. While a single access is atomic, a `lock` will still be needed if you want to read or write multiple fields as one atomic operation. (well, not technically always -- there are certain optimizations you can sometimes do, but stick to the simple stuff while you're learning)

So in short: the `lock` there is quite overkill -- you can get rid of it and use volatile/barriers if you require immediate visibility.